# How can we pass data between child components in angular 14 ? Please give suggesstion if uou know

Tags: angular

**I want to pass data from one child component to another child component in angular ?**

**Is it possible to do that ? if yes then how ?**

Comment: Yes, via input/output bindings or services that get injected into the child-components.

Answer (score 1):

Sharing data between not related components: When there is no relation between the component we can not pass the data using @Input. This happens when your components are in different modules. There are other scenarios when you have list of products and click on a particular product and then redirect to product details components. In these kinds of scenarios, we have to use data service to share data between components.

Complex Scenario- Sharing data using BehaviourSubjects
For creating data service. We have to define BehaviorSubject. BehaviorSubject holds the current value and the last value.

I always prefer to use BehaviorSubject because of following reasons:

It automatically updates the lates value wherever subscribed.
Always give last value when called via getValue() method.
No need to call next, just create a set and get method in order to get value.
In the data service, I have created messageSource as BehaviorSubject. This accepts editDataDetails as any. We can create editDataDetails as the type of Product interface which is a much better practice. Create changeMessage method which will set the current value of observables.

OR you can use this method

Sharing data between sibling components: Sharing data between siblings can be done by using points 1 and 2. First share data between the child to parent using output decorator and EventEmitter. Once received data in parent component share it to another child component using Input decorator. So siblings can talk each other via parent components.

More info: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/5-ways-to-share-data-between-angular-components-d656a7eb7f96